# regex for numeric only plus 'h' character only

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate string only if contains numerics and/or 'h' or 'H' character anywhere in the string.

e.g.

> 123 - valid
>   123h - valid
>   1h23 - valid
>   h234 - valid
>   123H - valid
>   asdf - **invalid**
>   123d - **invalid**

I am able to restrict string for numerics only but not with additional requirement of h. how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^\d*h?\d*$
```

Together with the ignore case option.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31dv1)

`^` anchor to the start of the string.

`\d*` match 0 or more digits

`h?` match 0 or 1 h

`\d*` match 0 or more digits

`$` anchor to the end of the string.

Comment: This will not work for `12H` that is `H` somewhere in the middle.
`^\d*h?H?\d*$` will be the correct one.

Comment: @VishalSuthar sure it will work. Have you read my explanation or tried the regexr link? Yours would match 1hH123

Comment: @stema yes I have tried that's why I am telling you. It will only match small `h` not the capital `H`.

Comment: @VishalSuthar, that why I wrote "Together with the ignore case option"

Comment: @VishalSuthar c# does also know options. Either use the inline modifier `(?i)` at the start of the regular expression or use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` when you create or call your regex object.

Answer (score 3):

`[0-9h]*` will match any digits 0-9 or h. To only allow one, "h" you could use `[0-9]*h?[0-9]*` (I assume you are already doing case-insensitive). You could also limit the number of digits surrounding the h as in `[0-9]{1,2}h?[0-9]{1,2}`.

Lets get really carried away and assume you want to allow 0-59 to be entered as minutes, or in an hours and minutes format with a separating 'h':

```
[0-9]{1,2}h[0-5]?[0-9]|[0-5]?[0-9]
```

Comment: Something like that would also match `1hhhh23h`, which I do not think is something that the OP is after.

Comment: nice. but I want h to appear only once in the string. will it work for that also?

Comment: How about: `[0-9]*[hH]?[0-9]*` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you `/[\dh]*/i`

Your examples are tested [here](http://rubular.com/r/yMvpgop5Qd).

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid regerx:

```
^\d*h?H?\d*$
```

Look here : [Regex Example](http://regexr.com?31dvg)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

`[^h]*h?[^h]*`

this should work.

Comment: No this will not work. It requires a `h` in the string and `!"§$'#*+~` would be also valid.

Comment: The `h` is now optional. the negated character class `[^h]` is still matching every character that is not a `h`, and that are far too much.